# Wireless is Connected but No access to Internet 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking, toshiba

I got my wireless to work finally after initial issues. Now I have moved locations, I can't get Internet access. Wireless is still connected but that is all. I am not tech savy nor Ubuntu-savy so help is greatly appreciated.  What do I need to do?

Update:

> lo no wireless extensions.
>
> eth1 no wireless extensions.
>
> wlan1 IEE bgn ESSID:"westell7668"
>
> Mode:Manged Frequency:2,437 GHz Access Point: 74:44:01:AC:07:B7
>
> Bit Rate=18 Mb/s Tx-Power=20dBm
>
> Retry long limit:7 RTS thr=2347 B Fragment thr:off
>
> Power Management:off
>
> Link Quality=55/70 Signal level=-55 dBm
>
> Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
>
> Tx excessive retries:0 Invalid misc:16 Missed beacon:0

Update:

I found out what it is. I had a network proxy on Google.com.

Comment: press `Ctrl+Alt+T` to open terminal, run `iwconfig`, and add the output.

Comment: I have added the output

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 13.04 for one, it's out now. You obviously can get to this site and ask this, download it, it's much better.

This seems to be an issue mostly with Rf kill ect. That works for most people. You can google or bing these results very easily. They can describe details much better than me.

One possible solution at the end of all others....Oddly we did this in backtrack 5 kde r3 when we had internet issues, add a wireless windows driver if you have a windows computer (Find the computer build through terminal, IOW exactly the computer name and details you're using, find all the drivers names on google for that computer hardware, install the specific up-to-date driver from the official driver website only (Use duckduckgo to find official websites, enable WOT website ratings in results.))

Comment: I am on a different computer and what does IOW and WOT mean?

Comment: **WARNING:** WOT-ratings may be (partly) ok, but do **NOT install any WOT-software**, it can/must be considered as malware!!! - https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html